# How to programmatically extract the text-messages from an iOS device via USB?

Tags: ios, iphone, reverse-engineering

Does anybody have an idea how I can **programmatically** extract iOS txt messages without locally backing it up with iTunes? It would actually be nice if I could simply run a **command line tool** like [idevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) or some **framework**/**API**.

[iMazing](http://imazing.com/features/transfer-iphone-text-messages-to-computer) seems to be doing just that - without jailbreaking the phone. *But how does this tool work?* Are they simply running a unencrypted backup task and then read the backup-files? Or is there an even more elegant way to access the text messages on an iOS device? (when plugged in via USB-cable)

Another idea could be that *iMazing* reverse-engineered Apples APIs, but this would be highly unlikely unless they hired some Apple engineers.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?